# SharePoint with C#

Tags: sharepoint-server

Hello I am new to SharePoint and I have seen code on C# using SPList, SPSecure, SPWeb, etc to connect to a sharepoint site, retrieve a List and do some operations.

However I cannot find a complete guide to develop such a "back-end". Is there any tutorial online?

Thanks

Comment: These objects are outdated and prone to a memory leak if it's not being used properly. Nowadays, SharePoint developers use CSOM or JSOM, or even the latest is using SharePoint Framework which is considered better and safer. May I know which version of SharePoint you're trying to develop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPSite/SPWeb/SPList is SharePoint Server Object which is used in SharePoint Server for developing like SharePoint Visual Web Part, Event Receiver , Custom Timer Job, please check the guide for a reference:

[SharePoint - Server Object Model](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sharepoint/sharepoint_server_object_model.htm)

If you are using SharePoint Online, Server Object Model is not available to use, should be using SharePoint CSOM/JSOM/Rest API:

[Complete basic operations using SharePoint client library code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code)

[Complete basic operations using JavaScript library code in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-javascript-library-code-in-sharepoint)

[Complete basic operations using SharePoint REST endpoints](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints)